# Why is bash on Ubuntu not loading aliases correctly?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

in /etc/profile.d/foo.sh I have:

```
set -o vi
export ECLIPSE_HOME=/usr/local/eclipse
alias eclipse=${ECLIPSE_HOME}/eclipse
```

After rebooting my Ubuntu 11.10 32-bit install, and after logging in from the GUI and opening a terminal as a regular user, and type `alias eclipse` the alias is not defined: `bash: alias: eclipse: not found`

If I then do `sudo su -` and then `alias eclipse` then I correctly get `alias eclipse='/usr/local/eclipse/eclipse'`

Just to be sure, if I then do (as root) `su - myusername` and then `alias eclipse` then I correctly get `alias eclipse='/usr/local/eclipse/eclipse'`

What gives?

Comment: try setting your terminal as a `login shell`

Comment: i use the terminal application in the default GUI

Comment: in the properties of that gui

Comment: I think it will be better using `~/.bashrc`, write those lines to `.bashrc` in your home directory.  And re open the terminal gui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to set aliases in bashrc than in profile.  profile is only read if you start a login shell.  bashrc is read whenever you start an interactive shell.

Comment: In addition to marking this as correct answer I would have also upvoted this if you had also mentioned /etc/bash.bashrc so it could apply to all users. Thanks regardless :)

Comment: I like separating out aliases into a separate ~/.bash_aliases file (and calling it from .bashrc), purely for organizational reasons.

Comment: @agksmehx I would have mentioned /etc/bash.bashrc, but that file can have different names in different distributions, and I wasn't sure what the Ubuntu version was called.  So rather than guess wrong, I just wrote "bashrc", assuming you would know what I meant.

Comment: ok, you have my upvote too. thanks for joining stackoverflow and helping out! :)